# How to change multiple elements css on hover of another?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of social links on my site, and when I hover one, I want the CSS of the others to change.

So, each default icon opacity will be set to 1, but when I hover one of these icons, I want to set the other icons opacity to 0.7. How do I do this?

Here is the CSS of the icons:

```
.fa {
  padding: 14px 8px !important;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.fa-facebook {
  color: white;
}


.fa-linkedin {
  color: white;
}

.fa-instagram {
  color: white;
  padding-right: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] -- the *most* important part of that is the HTML for a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```css
.fa 
{
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  margin: 0.25rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.icons
{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

/* target child with fa class on parent hover*/
.icons:hover > .fa 
{
  opacity: 0.7;
}

/* control child fa's opacity on both parent and self hover*/
.icons:hover > .fa:hover 
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="icons">
  <li class="fa fa-facebook">Facebook</li>
  <li class="fa fa-linkedin">LinkedIn</li>
  <li class="fa fa-instagram">Instagram</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cool, Glad I could help man.

Answer (score 0):

All links need to be in a container then you can put a hover event on the container that affects all the children.

```css
.social-container {
  display: flex;
}
.social-container:hover .fa {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.fa {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
.fa:hover {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-container">
  <div class="fa">Link</div>
  <div class="fa">Link</div>
  <div class="fa">Link</div>
</div>
```